# How do I initialise a new object that has a one-to-one relationship to another entity and then add that new object to the database?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4

I'm just starting to get the hang of Entity Framework 4 but there are still a few things that I'm struggling with, this problem is the latest and I was wondering if anyone would be so kind as to point me in the right direction?

I have a number of fairly simple entities in my model but one of them has a one-to-one relationship defined to another entity and I can't seem to find the right sequence of events to add a new instance of that entity to the database successfully.

**A simplified example**

I have a Student entity and a Nationality entity and a Student
has a one-to-one relationship to a Nationality

I am creating a new student entity to add to the database and
I can't persist it without first setting a nationality to satisfy
the one-to-one relationship.

I have a Nationality of "Not Known" as one of my Nationality entities in the database and I want this to be the initial value for my new student record.

How do I go about creating that new student, creating the initial reference to the "Not Known" nationality entity and then adding the new student record to the database in such a way that everything happens in the right order?

I am just using the standard classes generated alongside the model, I've had a look at STE's and POCO types but I decided to take a step back and learn the basics first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't know what "flavour" of EF are you using. Here's how to do it using EF Code First:
First your entities:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Nationality Nationality { get; set; }
}

public class Nationality
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
}
```

In this case the relationship is pretty simple and you don't need any [EntityTypeConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696117%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).
You can add your records in this order :

```
var nationalities = new List<Nationality>(){new Nationality(){Name ="Italian"},
                                                        new Nationality(){Name ="British"}, 
                                                        new Nationality(){Name ="American"}};

nationalities.ForEach(x => context.Nationality.Add(x));
context.SaveChanges();

//retrieve the nationality from the context
var italianNationality = context.Nationality.Where(x => x.Name == "Italian").First();
//create the student and assign a nationality
var student = new Student() { Name = "Giorgio", Nationality = italianNationality };
context.Students.Add(student);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Here's your tables structure (With the Student table containing a FK to the nationality)

[image]

And here the results of the insert:

[image]

More info on Code First here: 
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx
And here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/28/ef-4-2-code-first-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed reply Giorgio, I'm using Model first but I can follow what you've done.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: I'm still getting the following exception "A relationship from the 'StudentNationalityCode' AssociationSet is in the 'Added' state. Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding 'NationalityCode' must also in the 'Added' state."  I'm going to try making a small test-app to diagnose just this problem.

Comment: I've tried your solution in an isolated project and it works perfectly Giorgio so my problem must lie elsewhere - this question has been answered however, thanks again for your assistance.